# Recyclerview scroll slow and stuck android

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, kotlin

I am using MathView inside row_item of recyclerview. When i Scroll my Recyclerview its scroll stuck. Is it possible the reason of stuck my recyclerView because of MathView?

In my code , Type = 3 is Mathview data

```
if (queList[position].type == 1 || queList[position].type == 2) {

    holder.txtQue!!.setText(Html.fromHtml(Html.fromHtml(queList[position].question).toString()))
    holder.math_txtQue?.visibility = View.GONE

    if (isQuestionAnswer(queList[position].is_correct, 1)) {
        holder.txtAnswer!!.setText(Html.fromHtml(Html.fromHtml(queList[position].opt_1).toString()))
        holder.math_txtAnswer?.visibility = View.GONE
    }
    if (isQuestionAnswer(queList[position].is_correct, 2)) {
        holder.txtAnswer!!.setText(Html.fromHtml(Html.fromHtml(queList[position].opt_2).toString()))
        holder.math_txtAnswer?.visibility = View.GONE
    }

} else if (queList[position].type == 3) {

    holder.txtQue?.visibility = View.GONE
    holder.math_txtQue?.visibility = View.VISIBLE
    holder.math_txtQue?.text = Html.fromHtml(queList[position].question).toString()
    holder.mathDesc?.text = Html.fromHtml(queList[position].description).toString()

    if (isQuestionAnswer(queList[position].is_correct, 1)) {
        holder.txtAnswer?.visibility = View.GONE
        /*holder.math_txtAnswer?.visibility = View.VISIBLE
    holder.math_txtAnswer?.text = Html.fromHtml(queList[position].opt_1).toString()*/
    }

    if (isQuestionAnswer(queList[position].is_correct, 2)) {
        holder.txtAnswer?.visibility = View.GONE
        holder.math_txtAnswer?.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        holder.math_txtAnswer?.text = Html.fromHtml(queList[position].opt_2).toString()
    }

}
```

My Layout file :-

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/questionReadList"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar_top"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:divider="@null"
    android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"
    android:dividerHeight="0dp"></android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
```

Comment: Show some code please.

Comment: i add my code of adapter @Tepits

Comment: If your RecyclerView is inside NestedScrollView that can cause this effect. Do post your layout xml if possible.

Comment: It is possible that you are doing some time taking operation in the bind method of adapter, you can debug it by commenting all lines and then add them one by one to find the issue

Comment: No i don't use  NestedScrollView, i add xml layout please check it out @Abilash

Answer (score 0):

There are various reason for this problem and the solution respectively.

1. If you are using `RecyclerView` inside `NestedScrollView`.

   > False in your case
2. The code you have posted is already doing too much complex or logical work after inflating the View i.e. in `onBindViewHolder()` method.

   > For this
   >   you first try to comment all the logic, just try to inflate only the `View`

you can do the all the logical operation at the time of `JSON` Parsing. inflate the `View` as per your quesType using `getItemViewType()` & `viewType` implementation.

may this help you

Comment: means you say i comment dynamic data and my conditions and check only view am i right? @Abhinav Suman

Comment: Yes @Maulik, it can help you to understand why this is happening. and then work on that issue.

Comment: sure @Abhinav , hanks for help

Comment: @Maulik, Make the tick mark visible on the answer by accepting it as correct if my answer helps you. 
happy coding :-)